# How to set a value when the name of the value isn't known until runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am trying to set the properties of one object to be the same as the properties of another object. Here the code so far:

```
private T SetObjectAttributes<T> (dynamic fromO, T toO)
{
    foreach (var prop in fromO.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        toO[prop] = fromO[prop];
    }
    return toO;
}
```

The syntax here is incorrect:

```
toDbObject[prop] = fromObject[prop];
```

Basically, I am trying to set a property but the property name isn't known until run time.  So my question is how to assign the value of the property at runtime.

Comment: You may use AutoMapper for these purposes http://automapper.org/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the methods `GetValue( object sourceObject)` respectively `SetValue( object target, object value )` of the PropertyInfo instance of the property.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [PropertyInfo.SetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yc9sss5d) to actually set the value. Also I hope you're caching those PropertyInfo instances - because it's going to really slow otherwise.

You should also look at [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) or some other options.

What exactly are you trying to do? Perhaps there's an altogether better way.